# Button background hidding button text. Why?

Tags: android, button, android-layout, background, background-image

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget30"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:background="@drawable/v_fundo"
>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/v_titulo" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</ImageView>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget32" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/v_personagem">        </ImageView>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/v_balao" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/lastComicButton"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/v_transparente" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></ImageView>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:background="@drawable/funcoes_fundo" android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/button2" 
            android:text="Yes, we can!"
            android:background="@drawable/funcoes_1">
        </Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="65dp" 
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2" 
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2" 
            android:layout_width="250dp" 
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2" 
            android:background="@drawable/funcoes_2">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The button with id `button2` (`android:id="@+id/button2"`) shows the text fine in the Emulator and on the Milestone II.

However, when I put the `.apk` into the Motorola Defy, the image background of the button hides its text ("Yes, we can!"). I am sure of that because if I don't show the background (by deleting the line `android:background="@drawable/funcoes_1"`), the text is shown fine in the button.

Does anybody have any clue on why the background image of the Button is hiding its text in some devices (like the Motorola Defy)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your layout code is all wrong. You should never be doing `android:layout_alignRight=@+id/blah` it should just be `@id/blah` since you have already defined the id in your R.java file

Comment: I have fixed the problem. For some reason the default color of the text on the Motorola Defy was white. And, once my background was also white, I wasn't able to see the text. So, all I needed to do was to set the textcolor to black (#000000).

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
```

These should all be set to either "true" or "false".  These properties are used to determine in a RelativeLayout the "relative" gravity/alignment of a member.

Declaring android:id="@+button2" once is enough.

What is likely happening is the device it doesn't work on has an older or different version of Android that is not tolerant of this error.

Hope this helped.